# How to do IIS 6.0 debugging from the code that is published to a folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to do debugging from IIS 6.0 and here is the scenario. I have a web application and I published onto a physical folder (Say FolderA) in my machine. I then merged it with another folder (say FolderB) to integrate the functionality together (essentially, folder merge of bin, images, js, css folders etc). I then mounted FolderB on IIS in my local machine as a new website.

Now, I would want to debug a specific page in the website through IIS. Is this possible? AFAIK, the code in VS got disconnected from code in IIS and so w3wp.exe wouldn't be able to track back to the code that I have in VS. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, open the **Debug** menu and select the **Attach to Process** option. In the list of processes displayed you should find **aspnet_wp.exe**. Select this process and click Attach. Debugging your code should now be possible.

Set a breakpoint in your web application code at the required location and when you open the relevant page in your browser, your breakpoint should be triggered in VS.

Hope this helps.